# new - TypeError: undefined is not a Function

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, typeerror, node-sqlite3

I wrote a simple JS node file to query SQLite3 database with information I found on the Internet.

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

var db = new sqlite3.database("restful.db");

var sql = "SELECT * FROM sensors";

db.all(sql, [], function(err, rows) {

   if (err) {
       throw err;
   }

   rows.forEach(function(row) {

       console.log(row.name);
   });

});

db.close();
```

However, I keep running into an error message as shown in the following image.

[image]

I have checked other similar questions, but they are not as helpful.

Isn't new an operator? What am I doing Wrong?

Comment: It should be `sqlite3.Database`, not `sqlite3.database`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the sqlite3 docs https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3

`database` starts with an uppercase `D` as opposed to the lowercase `d`

so this

```js
var db = new sqlite3.database("restful.db");
```

should be this

```js
var db = new sqlite3.Database("restful.db");
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. Am I suppose to use double Quotation Mark or single within the parentheses?